# How laravel handles same get routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-routing

I am building a custom routing system for my home grown framework. My question is how laravel handles same routes in their routing system. for example

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
    return $user->email;
});

Route::get('api/user/{pass}', function (App\User $user) {
    return $user->email;
});
```

the number of the arguments in the route `api/user/{pass}` & `api/users/{user}` are same. How they do this ?.  How they differentiate the routes ?. How the matching process works ?.

Comment: The two routes are different. One says users and the other says user.. It will use whichever one you put out of the two. Sorry if I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel looks for routes secuentially, this means given two routes with the same endpoint, it will always call the first one found and stop there, so the second one it will never be reached, for example:

```
// Your url is user/johndoe

// It will start looking for a match

Route::get('user/{name}', function ($name) { // This route is a match 
    // This callback is called and Laravel stops searching
    return $name;
});

Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) { // This route is also a match
    // But a callback is already been called so this one is never reached
    return $id;
});
```

In case you want to differentiate both routes you can do so using regex:

```
Route::get('user/{name}', function ($name) {
    // This callback will only be executed when a word is passed in
})->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');

Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    // This callback will only be executed when a number is passed in
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

As you can see, both of this routes have the same endpoint, but now they will filter the parameter given according to the regex you provide.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will take the first route of the two only, since they are basically the same. It has no way to differentiate the two routes. If one of the routes method would be different (i.e put or post instead of get) then both routes would work. –

Comment: but the problem is if it can't differentiate the routes, it will execute the 2 callbacks tho ..

Comment: Well I think you should use the same route for the two since it's basically the same. You could also do something like :      
    Route::get('api/user/{user}/{pass}', function (App\User $user, App\User $pass) {
    return $user->email;
});

Comment: but how they differentiate it ?.  do they use regex or anything else ?

Comment: It does not differentiate, it chooses the first one between the two and thats it. As soon as it matches a route, it's done.

Comment: i don't think so dude.  if it does the routing like you said it will instantiate a wrong call back.. think..

Comment: Usually frameworks like Symfony and Laravel for example will they use regex. But as soon as a route is matched, that route is called and executed. It looks at the route from top to bottom and choses the first one it comes across that matches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152405/discussion-between-coder-1432-and-jijo-john).

Comment: but if there are 2 same routes with a different callback, how it handles that ?

Comment: Laravel tries to match the route first and executes the callback AFTER. So even if one of the two routes has a different callback it does not care, it will still match the first route that it comes across and then it will look at the callback and execute it. So the order of the routes from top to bottom is important.

Comment: /user/{user}/pass/{pass}/
/login/{card}/token/{token}/
these two routes will match .. because number of parameters are same.. @coder_1432 .. and what you mean by top to bottom ?

Comment: No these two routes are not the same. Because one starts with /user/ and the other with /login/. If the routes have the same number of params, and the rest of the url is the same, then it will match the first of the two. But in the scenario you just described, the params are the same but not the rest of the url. I think you should go read the Laravel documentation because this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Perfect glad it helped. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.